# Aplicar uma funcao a um dataframe R

Tags: r, dplyr

Criei uma função para verificar automaticamente se o valor de uma coluna está contido em uma lista. Eu poderia fazer dplyr::mutate + dplyr::ifelse, mas como são para muitas colunas, ficaria um código muito longo. A função funciona fora do mutate, mas nao nele.

O que eu fiz:

```
see_if_succed <- function(x,y){
  
  if (x %in% y) {
    1
  } else {
    0
  }
  
}
```

Fora do pipe a função funciona:

```
succeed <- c(1,5,8,9)
see_if_succed(100,succeed)
#0
```

Mas dentro do pipe não:

```
succeed <- c(1,5,8,9)
a <- c("A","B", "C")
b <- c(1,2,1)

y <- data.frame(a,b)

library(dplyr)

y %>%
  mutate(z = see_if_succed(b, succeed))
# a b z
# 1 A 1 1
# 2 B 2 1
# 3 C 1 1
# Warning message:
#   Problem with `mutate()` input `z`.
# i the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
# i Input `z` is `see_if_succed(b, succeed)`.
```

Alguém poderia me dizer como eu faço para essa função funcionar em um dataframe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eis uma resposta muito simples para um problema frequente.
Quando se pretende criar uma variável binária baseada numa condição, não é necessário `if`, ou `ifelse`. Como os valores lógicos `FALSE/TRUE` são codificados internamente como os números inteiros `0/1`, basta transformar o valor da condição em vetor de classe `"integer"`.

```
see_if_succed <- function(x, y) as.integer(x %in% y)

y %>%
  mutate(z = see_if_succed(b, succeed))
#  a b z
#1 A 1 1
#2 B 2 0
#3 C 1 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Por causa da condicional `if`, a tua função foi criada para ser aplicda em um elemento de cada vez. Tanto que esse é o warning que é dado:

> the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Uma maneira de resolver esse problema é vetorizando a função original. Particularmente, a forma que considero mais prática para fazer isso é através do comando `Vectorize`:

```r
see_if_succed_v <- Vectorize(see_if_succed, vectorize.args = "x")

y %>%
  mutate(z = see_if_succed_v(b, succeed))
#>   a b z
#> 1 A 1 1
#> 2 B 2 0
#> 3 C 1 1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Note que apenas criei uma função nova chamada `see_if_succed_v`, informando que o argumento `x` da função `see_if_succed` é o que deveria ser considerado para a vetorização. Assim, o resultado da coluna `z` no data frame final tornou-se o esperado com a aplicação de `see_if_succed_v` linha por linha.